# executing third party javascript (served from some DB) in a safe way

Tags: javascript, jslint, google-caja

I am building an application, where user-generated javascript functions are being stored in the database and in return are served to a number of other users.
The scripts will have to be validated by a person with admin rights (who *should* be trustable - but they are selected by the users themselves and therefore a kind of validation seems to be neccessary)

The Functions which will be executed are primary just for calculation purposes - no access to the DOM or (at least at this moment) any global objects is needed.

Let´s say a user defines a function counting the words of a string (as a simple example).

My approach at the moment is to wrap the function in a closure, pass an object with the input properties and define a local var window inside it to make this global object inaccessable (obviously this is not enough - iterating through all the properties of the window object and defining them locally might be a possibility but that in return might break some important functionality and it will not be enough)

Next idea was to wrap the function in an ADsave call on-the-fly to prevent functionality which might be harmful (and access to the global scope) but this would require that the code is verified via JSLint / adsave option on-the-fly (and I just can not find any material on how-to-do this... !)

Next approach is to use something like Caja (which would in fact remove the possibility to easily add new functions as the javascript code has to be 'transformed' into the Caja version of the code (and that can not be done by my own application on-the-fly).

As I´ll have to verfiy the functions whenever they are returned from the server (not just when they´ve been created on the client), ADsave seems to be the best solution so far

Does anyone have solution to the problems mentioned above (or possibly a better solution - I mean executiong third party jscript(served from some DB) in a safe way should be a quite common task nowadays.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! how would I write tests for an function which is not defined yet ? and how would those test prevent the execution of possibly harmful code (e.g. by accessign the global scope) ?

Comment: Think of providing features to define parameters (any no of parameters) and expected result. So you are not writing the tests, you are providing a framework only.

Comment: Your idea sound interesting - although I have to admit that I am not sure how to implement this (at the moment I am using QUint for testing). Do you thing about test performing some regular expressions on the function string (the functions are actually stored in a kind of HashMap) ? Would I have to test for the use of things like eval(), window. , document. and stuff like that ? I fear that doing so would ensure that I miss some vital security leaks. But probably I´m understanding your commend wrong (and it might be quite likely that I lack the necessary knowledge as well...) regards, matthias

Comment: I will try to have a closer look at the two approaches given here and (quite likely) return later on. Right now I do thanks the both of you for your dedication and help - it seems that I lack the necessary rights to gibe the both of you credit for your effords (and as I am not 100% sure that the answer provided is the actual solution to my problem , although I am positive that it points towards the right direction it would not seem fair for others searching for a similar solution to mark it as the correct answer). Once more: thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an approach you're trying to avoid, but I would simply execute the Javascript in an `<iframe>`.

Use an iframe that loads a page with only the required Javascript attached, and all your sandboxing will be taken care of for you.

**Edit** - as discussed in the comments to this answer, to prevent scripts in the iframe from accessing the parent document, you can host the iframe page on a subdomain. This way browsers will use separate cookies and will deny access to the window.parent object.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ! I have actually thought about that approach but I am kind of converned with the fact, that the use of iframes does (from my knowledge) not prevent e.g. the stealing of cookies (read about it some time ago) and the access of the global scope - do you have any thoughts about this ? regards, matthias

Comment: Yes, good point - both of these issues can be security concerns. The best way to get round this is to have the iframe page on a different domain or subdomain. That way browsers will use separate cookies and deny access to the window.parent object. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach (although it is quite likely a very good one - concerning that it would provide a maximum of flexibility for the executed code) is that the functions are stored in a kind of hashmap (as strings). I call them by doing something like this (... = new Function(param, code) ...) - that means I would have to create an iframe (via jquery,...) on-the-fly, meaning that it would be created by code from my base domain and therefore would have access to all it functionalities (and the security problem would persist) - any ideas on that ? - regards, matthias

Answer (score 1):

> Next approach is to use something like Caja (which would in fact remove the possibility to easily add new functions as the javascript code has to be 'transformed' into the Caja version of the code (and that can not be done by my own application on-the-fly).

On modern browsers (those with sufficiently correct implementations of the ECMAScript 5 standard), [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) does not need to perform major transformations of content and can operate in an entirely client-side fashion, including support for `eval()`.